# Access object method in function scope

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

So, I have a flask app, I am using [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) to structure project,
Calling flask_restful.Api()'s add_resource method, inside function is not working, I have tried using global keyword. I wanted to add it to function, also please explain reason behind this behavior.

```
db = MongoEngine()
rest_api = Api()

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object("openforms.config.Config")
    register_extensions(app)
    return app


def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    #global rest_api is also not helping
    rest_api.init_app(app)
    rest_api.add_resource(FormAPI,"/form/") #This is not working
```

But adding it outside the function is working,

```
db = MongoEngine()
rest_api = Api()

def create_app(test_config=None):
    ...
def register_extensions(app):
    ...
rest_api.add_resource(FormAPI,"/form/") #This is working
```

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: There is no error

Comment: Adding route inside function, just didn't work

Comment: So, do you call `register_extensions()`? The function should be called to execute code inside it. Out something from it.

Comment: Look at `create_app`, Also there is no issue with`register_extension` func because db is working